# Microsoft graph how to retrieve ALL SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperties of an Office 365 e-mail Message

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am able to add a SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperties, and retrieve properties by filtering by id.
but `.Expand("singleValueExtendedProperties")` Always returns `singleValueExtendedProperties=null` in the `Microsoft.Graph.Message`

I am trying to reverse engineer the way Outlook sends "Use Voting Buttons". I am under the impression Voting Button information is sent as SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperties, but I am unable to see any SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperties without knowing the Id.

Comment: You must specify the extended properties you want. Expansion will not work on extended properties. I suggest you try looking up posts on how this was done with EWS. Here's a couple that I found: [1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/exchange/en-US/1e3162ef-6afe-446a-9715-24a6d57f5d5e/how-to-send-email-with-voting-button-by-using-exchange-web-services-ews-java-api-11) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012883/send-voting-email.)

Comment: With EWS it was possible to send a message using Outlook and use EWS to reverse engineer the message content to workout the vote message properties. But given "ExtendedProperties" are optional and I know of no way of selecting ALL "ExtendedProperties" I can not specify what key required to retrieve the "ExtendedProperties". I am not even sure if the voting mechanism uses SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperties. I find it hard to believe all "ExtendedProperties" of a Microsoft.Graph Message can not be retrieved as some sort of collection.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the properties you want. However, you can retrieve the voting options and the vote response. Example below assume you have a valid bearer token and have the folderId and messageId variables set in a windows cmd window for a message with voting buttons or a vote response.

The vote options are available as a Base64 String encoding the bytes of the vote structure from Exchange using the following:

```
curl -v -s -H "Authorization: Bearer %token%" "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/Non-Prod_Timesheet_Assistant@calpers.ca.gov/mailFolders/%folderId%/messages/%messageId%?expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id%20eq%20'Binary%20{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}%20Id%200x00008520')"
```

where 0x00008520 comes from the documentation for the vote options:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidlidverbstream-canonical-property

Similarly, the vote response can be read as a Unicode string:

```
curl -v -s -H "Authorization: Bearer %token%" "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/Non-Prod_Timesheet_Assistant@calpers.ca.gov/mailFolders/%folderId%/messages/%messageId%?expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id%20eq%20'String%20{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}%20Id%200x00008524')"
```

where the ID 0x00008524 comes from the documentation for the response:
https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidlidverbresponse-canonical-property

In both cases, the properties come from the PSETID_Common property set which has the GUID 00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/e11cc753-cecf-4fdc-bec7-23304d12388a