# Send Vote options with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way, in Microsoft Graph API, using singleValueExtendedProperties or multiValueExtendedProperties, to send an email with voting options?

I can do it with using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices and the following code, but I need a way to do it in Microsoft Graph API

```
public byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
{
    if (hex.Length % 2 == 1)
        throw new Exception("The binary key cannot have an odd number of digits");

    byte[] arr = new byte[hex.Length >> 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length >> 1; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = (byte)((GetHexVal(hex[i << 1]) << 4) + (GetHexVal(hex[(i << 1) + 1])));
    }

    return arr;
}

public int GetHexVal(char hex)
{
    int val = (int)hex;
    //For uppercase A-F letters:
    //return val - (val < 58 ? 48 : 55);
    //For lowercase a-f letters:
    //return val - (val < 58 ? 48 : 87);
    //Or the two combined, but a bit slower:
    return val - (val < 58 ? 48 : (val < 97 ? 55 : 87));
}

public void TestEmail()
{
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
    service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("xxxxxx@xxxxxx.xxx", "xxxxxxxxx");
    service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
    EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);
    email.ToRecipients.Add("xxx@xxxxxxx.xxx");
    email.Subject = "Approval test from C#";
    email.ReplyTo.Add("xxx@xxxxxxx.xxx");


    string Header = "02010600000000000000";
    string ReplyToAllHeader = "055265706C790849504D2E4E6F7465074D657373616765025245050000000000000000";
    string ReplyToAllFooter = "0000000000000002000000660000000200000001000000";
    string ReplyToHeader = "0C5265706C7920746F20416C6C0849504D2E4E6F7465074D657373616765025245050000000000000000";
    string ReplyToFooter = "0000000000000002000000670000000300000002000000";
    string ForwardHeader = "07466F72776172640849504D2E4E6F7465074D657373616765024657050000000000000000";
    string ForwardFooter = "0000000000000002000000680000000400000003000000";
    string ReplyToFolderHeader = "0F5265706C7920746F20466F6C6465720849504D2E506F737404506F737400050000000000000000";
    string ReplyToFolderFooter = "00000000000000020000006C00000008000000";

    string ApproveOption = "0400000007417070726F76650849504D2E4E6F74650007417070726F766500000000000000000001000000020000000200000001000000FFFFFFFF";
    string RejectOtion = "040000000652656A6563740849504D2E4E6F7465000652656A65637400000000000000000001000000020000000200000002000000FFFFFFFF";
    string VoteOptionExtras = "0401055200650070006C00790002520045000C5200650070006C007900200074006F00200041006C006C0002520045000746006F007200770061007200640002460057000F5200650070006C007900200074006F00200046006F006C00640065007200000741007000700072006F00760065000741007000700072006F007600650006520065006A0065006300740006520065006A00650063007400";
    string DisableReplyAllVal = "00";
    string DisableReplyVal = "00";
    string DisableForwardVal = "00";
    string DisableReplyToFolderVal = "00";

    email.Body = new MessageBody();
    email.Body.BodyType = BodyType.HTML;
    email.Body.Text = "Body";
    ExtendedPropertyDefinition VOTE_DEF = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Common, 0x8520, Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType.Binary);

    byte[] bytes = StringToByteArray(Header + ReplyToAllHeader + DisableReplyAllVal + ReplyToAllFooter + ReplyToHeader + DisableReplyVal + ReplyToFooter + ForwardHeader + DisableForwardVal + ForwardFooter + ReplyToFolderHeader + DisableReplyToFolderVal + ReplyToFolderFooter + ApproveOption + RejectOtion + VoteOptionExtras);
    email.SetExtendedProperty(VOTE_DEF, bytes);
    email.SendAndSaveCopy();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes using EWS API you can do this. But i failed to notice any documentation how to do so. Being said that i remember a [related thread talks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59204356/microsoft-graph-how-to-retrieve-all-singlevaluelegacyextendedproperties-of-an-of) about this and see how you can use MAPI extended properties. If nothing works, consider filing an [uservoice item](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?query=vote)(feature request) with Microsoft Graph team, so that they can consider implementing it.